# Make multiple HTTP requests/responses when 4xx response loses the connection

Tags: .net, http, rest, httpwebrequest, tcpclient

I am working on a client for a REST API. The server returns 4xx responses as a matter of course. At the moment, I am using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse to make the calls. The problem is that HttpWebRequest throws an exception on 4xx (and 5xx) codes. I am catching the exception, and then (usually) sending another request based on the data in the 4xx message (e.g., try POST, then MERGE in a failure).

This works, but having to recreate the TCP/HTTP connection every time is expensive. What I want to be able to do is a get a response stream or object that has the response data, but does *not* throw an exception, allowing me to make another request on the connection (via keep-alive). This should reduce the connection overhead, and boost performance.

One way I have looked at is using the TcpClient directly, but that is a headache, as I then have to write code to support chunked data, encodings, proxies, etc. I am hoping to avoid this.

Is there a way to prevent WebExceptions using the System.Net HTTP client? If not, are there any other options (hopefully open source)? Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Are you SURE that the underlying connection is actually closed and not simply pooled (you did enable KeepAlive, right?). You can check with Fiddler's Timeline view tab; right-click and choose Client Port Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why your HTTP connection would be getting closed due to an exception, however, if you use the HttpClient from here http://nuget.org/List/Packages/HttpClient it does not throw an exception on a 400.